# Why does std::set::find not provide a hint iterator?

Tags: c++, performance, c++11, c++17, standards

```
#include <set>
#include <vector>

using Value = std::vector<int>;

int main()
{
    auto coll = std::set<Value>{};

    // ......
    // Insert many values here.
    // ......

    auto new_value = Value{1, 2, 3};
    auto const pos = coll.find(new_value);

    if (pos != coll.end())
    {
        // Good
        coll.emplace_hint(coll.erase(pos), std::move(new_value));
    }
    else
    {
        // Performance penalty!
        // No hint here, though coll.find(new_value) knows that.
        coll.emplace(std::move(new_value));
    }
}
```

**Why does** `std::set::find` **not provide a hint iterator?**

Comment: I'm not sure how that iterator would look. You could perhaps use `std::set::lower_bound` instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The result of `std::set::lower_bound()` is usable as a hint for `emplace_hint()`.  So just use `lower_bound()` instead of `find()`, and check if the key returned by `lower_bound()` matches what you were looking for, instead of checking if the iterator returned by `find()` is `end()`.

Comment: This should be advertised better. Or probably I'm just ignorant...

Comment: @CostantinoGrana: I somewhat agree, but real-world code rarely uses any of the "hint" features in any containers, and people seeking ultimate performance are probably not going to use `std::set`.  Given that the feature is never going to be used much, more advertising seems unnecessary.

Comment: Thank you for answering. If I may, is there any alternative for `unordered_set`?

Comment: @CostantinoGrana: There are many.  One of the most recent which promises to become popular is https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_83_0/libs/unordered/doc/html/unordered.html#unordered_flat_set

Answer (score 0):

This would be troublesome when considering transitivity and symetry of the `==` operator for the iterator.

Let `i1` and `i2` be hints retrieved via `find` for different non-existing objects in `set`.

We have

- `i1 == set.end()`
- `set.end() == i2`

Therefore `i1 == i2`, so we'd expect this kind of hint to have the same behavior when inserting, but the desired behavior you described is a different behavior (improved performance of `emplace` when passing the iterator retrieved via a `find` on the same value you're emplacing).